# How to solve this S/R conflict

Tags: bison, lr-grammar, shift-reduce-conflict, jison

Here's a simplification of my working EBNF grammar:

```
%token NEWLINE BLOCK_MARK A
%start file

file: block+ NEWLINE*;
block: BLOCK_MARK line;
line: A+;
```

Both \n and EOF spit out NEWLINE as a token (so that a single ending NEWLINE isn't required before EOF). It works with a stream like this:

```
BLOCK_MARK A A BLOCK_MARK A NEWLINE[actually EOF]
```

Now I want to have several `line` in a `block`, at least one being mandatory and the rest separated with `NEWLINE`. E.g.:

```
BLOCK_MARK A A NEWLINE A A BLOCK_MARK A A A EOF
```

I tried doing this:

```
file: block+ NEWLINE*;
block: BLOCK_MARK line moreline*;
line: A+;
moreline: NEWLINE line;
```

But Jison complains about a S/R conflict when lookahead is `NEWLINE`. I guess the state machine is confused deciding if the `NEWLINE` is part of a new block `line` or the final `NEWLINE*` in `file` (which is needed because the file can end with NEWLINE/EOF).

How can I fix this?

Comment: One mechanism might be to stop treating newlines as EOF; they're not the same thing at all. I'm more than a little puzzled about how that is working.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's the other way around, I'm treating EOF as NEWLINE. I think I'm not the only one doing that to make an ending NEWLINE not required (since EOF is parsed as NEWLINE too). Changing `file` to `file: block+ NEWLINE* EOF` does not fix the issue and makes it worse, requiring both `NEWLINE` (for `line`) and `EOF` (for `file`) as the last parsed tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to make the newlines PART of the preceeding line, deferring a reduction of anything other than a line until after you see the newline.  So you end up with:

```
file: block+ ;
block: BLOCK_MARK line_nl+ line_nonl? | BLOCK_MARK line_nonl ;
line_nl: line NEWLINE ;
line_nonl: line ;
line: A+ ;
```

Now the only problem with the above is that it doesn't allow for any blank lines (a blank line will be a syntax error).  But that's the same as your original grammar.

Comment: I think that makes sense, thanks! I got the blank line covered in the scanner (\n+ spits NEWLINE).

Comment: Woops, didn't solve the whole issue since this now fails for the original use case (I think I ran into this already). `BLOCK_MARK A BLOCK_MARK A EOF` fails, but `NEWLINE` should only be required if there are at least two lines present! Compare with `BLOCK_MARK A NEWLINE A BLOCK_MARK A EOF`, which works fine (because there's at least a `NEWLINE` or EOF in `line`).

Comment: Adding an additional rule: `block: BLOCK_MARK line_nonl ;` should fix that.

Comment: My grammar is slightly more complex and I had to add an extra production covering both cases, but that solved the issue. I came up with another solution based on yours that seems to be fine too (the other answer), though I'll accept (and probably use) yours.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Chris Dodd's idea but reversed as it was in my frist try. The basic idea was just to remove the `NEWLINE*` at `file`, which was already covered in `line` after all.

```
file: block+;
block: BLOCK_MARK line_nonl line_nl* NEWLINE?;
line_nl: NEWLINE line_nonl;
line_nonl: A+;
```

I think this one solves all cases.